# External to something

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the sentence below (which is written in the context of **[Deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism) Theories**):

> All events are determined by cause external to the will

What is meant by `'external to the will'`?

I think it has a different meaning from *an outer sense*.

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi Elyar, what exactly are you unsure about?  Have you looked up the words in a good dictionary, for example this one: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/external (see OUTSIDE) and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will (see MENTAL POWER)

Comment: @JavaLatte , Sure! I know the denotative meaning of the words. I was wondering if this phrase has a sense of 'ineffectiveness of the will against the causes'?

Comment: No, it does not: it's much simpler. Turn it into an active voice sentence: "causes that are external to the will determine all events". Put simply, "you never get what you want".

Comment: So It does! :) You just confirmed it; "you never get what you want"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*External to the will* here can be translated to *outside of the will*. Here  *outside* has this sense:

> Beyond the limits or scope of

[[Oxford Dictionary of English]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/outside)

So you see, *external* does take a meaning related to *outside* here. In fact, it means

> Coming or derived from a source outside the subject affected.

[[Oxford Dictionary of English]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/external)

Your confusion may come from not being familar with *outside* or *external* being used in a context not describing physical structures such as rooms or buildings.

Comment: Being familiar with such context made me ask this question. I was wondering if this phrase has a sense of 'ineffectiveness of the will against the causes'? And with the help of your suitable analogical analysis, I think I was right (, but unsure) ...
Thanks for the references, which are so important to me.